# How to hide Undefined global vim warning in Neovim?

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

When I want to edit my neovim config files, it always shows 'Undefined global vim' warning. I don't like it. Although I tried some method to resolve this issue, it still exists.

- My lua lspconfig

```lua
lspconfig.lua_ls.setup(
    {
        on_init = function(client)
            local path = client.workspace_folders[1].name
            if not vim.loop.fs_stat(path .. "/.luarc.json") and not vim.loop.fs_stat(path .. "/.luarc.jsonc") then
                client.config.settings =
                    vim.tbl_deep_extend(
                    "force",
                    client.config.settings.Lua,
                    {
                        runtime = {
                            -- Tell the language server which version of Lua you're using (most likely LuaJIT in the case of Neovim)
                            version = "LuaJIT"
                        },
                        diagnostics = {
                          globals = { 'vim' }
                        },
                        -- Make the server aware of Neovim runtime files
                        workspace = {
                            library = {vim.env.VIMRUNTIME}
                            -- or pull in all of 'runtimepath'. NOTE: this is a lot slower
                            -- library = vim.api.nvim_get_runtime_file("", true)
                        }
                    }
                )

                client.notify("workspace/didChangeConfiguration", {settings = client.config.settings})
            end
            return true
        end
    }
)
```

- Screenshot
  [image]